# Children's SF book about moon folk going to live on another planet

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, moon

I remember reading a book, probably aimed at about a fourth grade level, in which there were aliens native to the moon. They decided to leave because more and more astronauts from earth were turning up. They headed off to live on another planet. Various semi-comedic adventures ensue. I honestly don't remember any details beyond that, though.

Comment: I'm willing to bet you do remember details beyond that. Have a look at the checklist here; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if anything comes to mind.

Comment: I remember some trivial stuff. One of the characters marking out roads on a map of a new planet before they get there. Astronauts leaving some garbage on the moon. Trivial stuff. But Winchell Chung actually nailed it below: It's the "Matthew Looney" series.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Matthew Looney](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Looney) series by Jerome Beatty jr.
Essentially as you described.

> The Matthew Looney books chronicle the adventures of a brother and
>   sister, Matthew and Maria Looney, who live in the town of Crater
>   Plato, on the Moon. In Beatty's stories, the inhabitants of the Moon
>   are a fully developed non-human civilization. Beatty's fictional Moon
>   inhabitants are an indigenous species, living on the Moon without the
>   assistance of spacesuits, "breathing" vacuum instead of air. A
>   recurring theme in the books is Matthew's desire to know more about
>   outer space, especially the Earth. At the beginning of the series, he
>   looks up in the sky at the Earth and wonders if anyone is living on
>   it.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU! That's exactly it! YES YES YES!
Unrelated: I just realized you're THE Winchell Chung of Atomic Rockets! I interviewed you a few years ago for the now-defunct "Republibot" website.
Small world, smaller internet.
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Happy to be of service! That was a good interview, too.